When are type assertions acceptable to use in TypeScript?
I've seen plenty of discussions and articles explaining why type assertions in TS are a bad practice, but I've never seen any explanations for when they are acceptable to use. Are there situations in which using type assertions produces a net benefit?

Most discussions and articles explaining that something is a bad practice are wrong. Why would something that is part of the language, that is documented, that serves a purpose, be a bad practice? Just use them.

What reasons are given for type assertions being bad? As with most of these discussions the answer is probably "it depends".

@EricMORAND implicit globals are in JS and are considered bad practice. And the promise constructor is in native JS yet is considered an anti-pattern in some cases. try/catch exists in many languages, yet using them for conditional control is frowned upon. Just because something exists, it's not automatically good to just use it willy-nilly.

@VLAZ at the opposite side of the scope, we have articles that explain that eval should not be used or that classes are good. I could easily write an article explaining why classes are an anti-pattern, and then would you stop using them?

@EricMORAND I meant to convey that not everything is absolutes. But you write any article you wish. I'd just continue not thinking in binary "yes/no" for concepts and evaluate them as needed.

@VLAZ that's exactly my point: saying that type assertions are bad practice - or any other pattern - is conveying an arbitrary and absolute truth that makes beginners not even consider some patterns that they could ultimately cherish and use appropriately. This is like preventing using a tool because some people use it the wrong way.

@EricMORAND except you claimed all articles are wrong. If you tried to advocate for nuance, you failed. Next time, don't do sweeping generalisations if your point is that there shouldn't be generalisations.

@VLAZ they are all wrong, by nature: they assert a truth - "this is bad practice" - that does not exist. Hence, they are wrong. Specifically here, any article that says that type assertions are bad practice is wrong: type assertions are not bad practice; how could an article that says that they are bad practice be anything else than wrong? The same applies for every other "bad practice" article.

@EricMORAND OK, so you're making an absolute claim here? Wasn't I supposed to not listen to those?

They are not a bad practice, and will never be. They are a useful tool, and sometimes an essential one that you can't not use if you want to benefit from type-checking.
Consider the following code sample that actually uses the typescript package itself to parse a source code and fails to compile:
import * as TS from "typescript";

const visitNode = (node: TS.Node) => {
    switch (node.kind) {
        case TS.SyntaxKind.NumericLiteral: {
            const text = node.text; // TS2339: Property 'text' does not exist on type 'Node'

            break;
        }

        default: {
            node.forEachChild(visitNode);
        }
    }
}

In order to have this source compile successfully, we have to hint the compiler that, inside the case TS.SyntaxKind.NumericLiteral block, node is of type TS.NumericLiteral. We know about that, there is no doubt since its kind is TS.SyntaxKind.NumericLiteral, but the type-checker doesn't; we have to let him know:
import * as TS from "typescript";

const visitNode = (node: TS.Node) => {
    switch (node.kind) {
        case TS.SyntaxKind.NumericLiteral: {
            const text = (node as TS.NumericLiteral).text;

            break;
        }

        default: {
            node.forEachChild(visitNode);
        }
    }
}

Type assertions are a tool, a very powerful one that should be used whenever it makes the type-checking more accurate.

okay to use sometimes. They help when the compiler doesn't know something that you do. For example, if you're getting data from an API or working with JSON, TypeScript might not know the exact type of that data. You can use a type assertion to tell it what type to expect.
Another time to use them is when dealing with HTML elements. If you select an element and you know it's a button or an input, you can assert its type so TypeScript understands how to handle it.
Just be careful not to overuse them. Type assertions tell the compiler to trust you, so if you're wrong, it won't catch the error and might struggle to find ther bug.
best to use type assertions when you're sure about the type and there's no other way to let TypeScript know.
